# Nested view pager with child fragment

Tags: android

I want to get nested fragment with a onClick method.I can't get the inner Fragment with his own xml working. After execution I get the following error:
**No view found for id 0x7f0d0086 (com.none.myapp:id/menu_fragment) for fragment InnerFragment.**
Is there a correct way to retrieve a inner Fragment using Viewpager?

FRAGMENT1 -->Button --->NESTED FRAGMENT

This is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private SectionsPageAdapter mSectionPageAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mSectionPageAdapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    setupViewPager(mViewPager);
    //Assigns the ViePager to TabLayout
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
}
//Defines the number of tabs by setting appropriate fragment and tab name.
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){
    SectionsPageAdapter adapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new ScanFragment(),"TEST1");
    adapter.addFragment(new FilesFragment(),"TEST2");
    adapter.addFragment(new QuizFragment(),"TEST3");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

}}
```

This is the outer Fragment:

```
public class TEST1 extends Fragment{
private Button btnTest1;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.quiz_layout, container, false);
    btnTest1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn1);

    btnTest1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getChildFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragContainer, new InnerFragment())
                    .commit();


        }

    });

    return view;
}

}
```

This is should be the inner Fragment:

```
public class InnerFragment extends Fragment{
public InnerFragment(){

}


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inner_fragment, container, false);

    return view;
}}
```

}

Outer xml Fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/fragContainer"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
    android:text="Quiz"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="207dp" />

 <FrameLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to get you fragment from pager by tag.

View Pager marks fragment with its own tag wich is android:switcher:viewId:index.

Here is simple method to do this.

```
private static String getFragmentTag(int viewPagerId, int fragmentIndex) {
      return "android:switcher:" + viewPagerId+ ":" + fragmentIndex;
}
```

Example how to get fragment from viewPager:

```
String fragmentTag = getFragmentTag(mViewPager.getViewId(), 0);// 0 - is pos of first fragment
Fragment yourFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);
```

But as far as I understand you want to get fragment inside fragment.
So basically you need to provide method which return this fragment from TEST1 fragment.

```
public class TEST1 extends Fragment{
    private Button btnTest1;

    private InnerFragment innerFragment = new InnerFragment()    

            @Nullable
            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.quiz_layout, container, false);
                btnTest1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn1);

                btnTest1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        getChildFragmentManager()
                                .beginTransaction()
                                .add(R.id.fragContainer, innerFragment )
                                .commit();


                    }

                });

                return view;
            }

       public InnerFragment getInnerFragment() {
            return innerFragment;
       }

 }
```

Comment: So. I should  use this method in the ViewPagerAdapter.Should I give the xml a tag name? can you please explain or provide a example?

Comment: That seems to working, but only for created fragments within the setupviewpager in MainActivity. I updated my question with the xml file of the outer fragment.Thanks.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more detailed what you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have tab layout with three fragments and each fragment has a button to get the inner fragment with his own layout. So the inner fragment will fill up the whole screen. For example Fragment --button--InnerFragment.I'm new to android and used activity and intents before. I'm trying to understand the fragment view pager concept.

Comment: In other words:The parent fragment will not be removed and the nested fragment layout is visible behind the parent fragment.

Comment: Yeap, basically you cant replace fragment inside viewpager, because viewpager manages fragment by it self. I would suggest you to read about it, and check if it fits to your needs. Other option is not to use VIewPager but just TabLayout and in onClick event replace fragment in activity's layout, so you will manage it by your self